# ESP8266 Subscribe to AWS IOT topic

Tags: mqtt, iot, esp8266

Hi I need to create a lambda function which will access the AWS thing and publish MQTT message, I'd like to get the published message on the ESP8266 which was connected to the thing as well, and controlled turn on/off the LED on ESP8266. So far I have uploaded the private.der, cert.der and ca.der to the ESP8266 absolutely, but it couldn't subscribed AWS IOT, please point me in the right tips then please share.

Code:

```
       #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
       #include <PubSubClient.h>
       #include <NTPClient.h>
       #include <WiFiUdp.h>
       #include <ArduinoJson.h>
       #define OUT_TOPIC "$aws/things/devices/shadow/update"
       #define IN_TOPIC "$aws/things/devices/shadow/update/delta"
        const char* ssid = "sid";
        const char* password = "password";

        WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
        NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "pool.ntp.org");

        const char* AWS_endpoint = "endpoint.amazonaws.com";//MQTT broker ip

        const char* json = "{\"state\":{\"reported\":{\"led\":\"off\"}}}";

        StaticJsonDocument<1024> doc;

        WiFiClientSecure espClient;
        PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient);//set MQTT port number to 8883 as per standard
        PubSubClient client(AWS_endpoint, 8883, espClient); 
        long lastMsg = 0;
        char msg[50];
        int value = 0;

        void setup_wifi() {

        delay(10);// We start by connecting to a WiFi network
        espClient.setBufferSizes(512, 512);
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Connecting to ");
        Serial.println(ssid);

        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
        }
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("WiFi connected");
        Serial.println("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

        timeClient.begin();
        while(!timeClient.update()){
        timeClient.forceUpdate();
        }

        espClient.setX509Time(timeClient.getEpochTime());

        int qos = 0;//Maximum size of data that can be communicated
        Serial.println(MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
        if(mqttClient.subscribe(IN_TOPIC, qos)){
        Serial.println("Subscribed.");
        Serial.println("Success!!");
        }

        deserializeJson(doc, json);
        JsonObject obj = doc.as<JsonObject>();

        if(mqttClient.publish(OUT_TOPIC, json)){
        Serial.println("Published!!");
        }

        }

        void setup() {

        Serial.begin(115200);
        Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
        // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
        pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
        setup_wifi();
        delay(1000);
        if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
        return;
        }

        Serial.print("Heap: "); Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());

        //replace cert.crt eith your uploaded file name
        File cert = SPIFFS.open("/cert.der", "r"); 
        if (!cert) {
        Serial.println("Failed to open cert file");
        }
        else
        Serial.println("Success to open cert file");

        delay(1000);
        if (espClient.loadCertificate(cert))
        Serial.println("cert loaded");
        else
        Serial.println("cert not loaded");

        // Load private key file
        File private_key = SPIFFS.open("/private.der", "r");//replace private eith your uploaded file name
        if (!private_key) {
        Serial.println("Failed to open private cert file");
        }
        else
        Serial.println("Success to open private cert file");

        delay(1000);

        if (espClient.loadPrivateKey(private_key))
        Serial.println("private key loaded");
        else
        Serial.println("private key not loaded");
        // Load CA file
        File ca = SPIFFS.open("/ca.der", "r"); 
        //replace ca eith your uploaded file name
        if (!ca) {
        Serial.println("Failed to open ca ");
        }
        else
        Serial.println("Success to open ca");

        delay(1000);

        if(espClient.loadCACert(ca))
        Serial.println("ca loaded");
        else
        Serial.println("ca failed");
        Serial.print("Heap: "); 
        Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
        }

        void callback (char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

        Serial.println("Received. topic=");
        Serial.println(topic);
        char subsc[length];
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        subsc [i]=(char)payload[i];
        subsc [length]='\0';
        Serial.print(subsc);
        }
        Serial.print("\n");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        }

        void mqttLoop() {
        mqttClient.loop();
        delay(100);
        //digitalWrite(LED_pin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
        Serial.print(".");
        }
        void loop() {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the older forms of `WiFiClientSecure` certificate handling.  I'll assume that's working OK and you're able to establish an SSL connection.

Your `IN_TOPIC` needs to be updated slightly to: `$aws/things/&lt;name-of-your-thing&gt;/shadow/update/accepted` (where hopefully you know what `&lt;name-of-your-thing&gt;` is).  You can get this from the thing shadow on your AWS console.

Similarly `AWS_endpoint` needs updating: it should be of the form `&lt;random-stuff-specific-to-you&gt;.iot.&lt;region&gt;.amazonaws.com`.  You can also find it from the same place as the MQTT topics.

You only want one instance of `PubSubClient`.  I'll assume you delete `client` and keep `mqttClient`.  You'll need to update the instantiation to include the AWS endpoint and port as you have done for client.

Before calling `mqttClient.subscribe(...)` you need to register the callback:

```
  mqttClient.setCallback(::callback);
```

then connect to AWS:

```
  mqttClient.connect("some-unique-name");
```

Finally, you need to edit `PubSubClient.h` (look for it in Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src) to update MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE. The default is 128 and I've found that too small with AWS's messages.  I've made mine 1024:

```
  #define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 1024
```

and that appears ample.

Once that compiles and runs you'll start seeing callback(...) called with the topics you've subscribed to and you can implement the function to do whatever you need.

The PubSubClient doesn't do much error reporting to help diagnose what's going on.  I'm currently refactoring it a bit and including more diagnostic information and will eventually issue a pull request.  Let me know if you'd like my hacked version before I get that far.